# Basic setup of Google Cloud DNS for Tomcat container

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I've recently setup a new Tomcat instance on Google Compute Engine and I can access my Tomcat instance via its IP address in the browser.

I've now setup a Cloud DNS entry and had my domain registrar point my domain name to the Cloud DNS servers. However this was 2 days ago and I still can't access my website via the domain name.

The WHOIS record shows the following Name Server entries

```
Name Server ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com
Name Server ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com  
Name Server ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com  
Name Server ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com
```

I've also setup an A record in the Cloud DNS console based on the feedback of my domain registrar. Is there anything else I need to setup in order for all this to work?

[EDIT 1] Having a look again at the instructions provided by Google it seems the name server names they wanted me to use have changed to

```
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com.
```

I've asked my registrar to make the change in case this is the problem.

[EDIT 2] My registrar has updated my DNS records and they resolve to Google's servers. However my website still doesn't show when entered into a browser I get an NXDOMAIN error, which implies my domain doesn't exist. Does anyone have a basic example of what the Cloud DNS settings should look like? Do I need to setup A records or CNAME records?

[EDIT3] My setup is shown here (domain name and IP addresses have been faked for screenshot)

[image: Cloud DNS screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally worked out the problem.

In the screenshot in my question the following changes were required.

1) Replace the A record for *.andtest.com.au with an A record for just andtest.com.au
2) Replace the www.andtest.com.au A record with a CNAME record for www.andtest.com.au which points to andtest.com.au

Now when I enter www.andtest.com.au in a browser, I see my Tomcat web page.

Comment: Did you mean that *.andtest.com.au means all www, ftp, mail to be mapped to the same IP?   If so, well CNAME is the way to go and glad you  finally got it working